# Determining the bounds of a polynomial with unknown, discrete, bounded coefficients and bounded, discrete x.

Tags: polynomials

Given a polynomial $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$, where $-7\le a, b, c, d, x\le7$, and $a, b, c, d, x$ **are integers**, is there a mathematical way that I can find the coefficients and value of $x$ that yield the maximum and minimum value of f(x)? Aka, what is the lowest possible value and highest possible value of f(x) given these constraints?

I brute-forced the solution in Java by doing 5 nested loops. For each combination of $a, b, c, d, x$ from $-7$ to 7 I calculated the polynomial and determined which values yielded the maximum and minimum.

Comment: Check where the polynomial is increasing or decreasing, where it is convex, where concave by differentiating it.

Answer (score 0):

Its obvious just by inspection that the maximum occurs when all five are $7$ and the minimum occurs when $a,b,c$ and $d$ are $-7$, and $x$ is $7$.

Comment: This is just an example. Is there a strategy where one can solve these types of problems mathematically, instead of by inspection?

Answer (score 0):

The maximim and minimum values of $ax^3, bx^2, cx$, and $d$ where $x$ is an integer, 
$-7 \le x \le 7$, and $-7 \le a,b,c,d \le 7$ will occur when $x=7$ and/or $x=-7$.

$$\text{For $x=7$}$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
   \text{term} & \text{Max Value is attained when} &
   \text{Min Value is attained when} \\
\hline
   ax^3 & a=7 & a=-7\\
   bx^2 & b=7 & a=-7 \\
   cx   & c=7 & a=-7 \\
   d    & d=7 & a=-7 \\
\hline
\end{array}

$$\text{For $x=-7$}$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
   \text{term} & \text{Max Value is attained when} &
   \text{Min Value is attained when} \\
\hline
   ax^3 & a=-7 & a=7\phantom{-}\\
   bx^2 & b= 7 \phantom{-} & a=-7 \\
   cx   & c=-7 & a=7\phantom{-} \\
   d    & d= 7 \phantom{-} & a=-7 \\
\hline
\end{array}

So the maximum value of $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ is
$$
   7 \cdot 7^3 + 7 \cdot 7^2 + 7 \cdot 7 + 7 =
   -7 \cdot (-7)^3 + 7 \cdot (-7)^2 - 7 \cdot (-7) + 7
$$

and the minimum value of $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ is
$$
   -7 \cdot 7^3 - 7 \cdot 7^2 - 7 \cdot 7 - 7 =
   7 \cdot (-7)^3 - 7 \cdot (-7)^2 + 7 \cdot (-7) - 7
$$